# Mandrill Status 'Queued' problem when im putting 'Sent'

Tags: python, sendmail, mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Im trying to create a send-template with Mandrill using Python. The code runs fine but im getting a 'Queued' Status instead of 'Sent'.

My Code:

```
import mandrill

MANDRILL_API_KEY = 'API-KEY'
email = 'email@example.com'
myEmail = 'email@example.com'
subjectMessage = 'Hi| Welcome Message'
template_content = [{'content': subjectMessage, 'name': 'SUBJECT'}]
mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY)
message = {'to': [{
               'email': myEmail,
               'name': 'Dear Applicant:',
               'type': 'to'
           }],
           'subject': subjectMessage,
           'from_email': email
           }

#result = mandrill_client.messages.send(message = message)
result = mandrill_client.messages.send_template(
    template_name='test-template', template_content=template_content, message=message, async=False, ip_pool=None, send_at=None)

# result is a dict with metadata about the sent message, including
# if it was successfully sent
print(result)
'''
[{'_id': 'abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123',
  'email': 'recipient.email@example.com',
  'reject_reason': 'hard-bounce',
  'status': 'sent'}]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: my code was working just fine. My account was on a trial version... So be sure to pay the mandrill